# Statically Combining HTML Files

Tags: html

I would like to build a very simple website as part of my application. This website will serve up the links relating to my application, for example the web-start link.

This website will have two or three pages. The top of each page will require the same header, containing a navigation bar. Thus, I would like to store the navigation bar in a single file and have it imported into the user-browsable HTML web pages.

I would like to perform this statically, prior to publishing the website. Such that the result is a plain-old-HTML site (i.e. I would like to avoid using javascript to dynamically perform the includes).

My java app is built using Maven. Any java-based application to perform this task that already has a maven plugin would be a bonus, although worst-case I don't mind writing the maven plugin myself.

Comment: I don't think HTML has any way to merge files. This is usually done with something like PHP, using its `include` statement.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not looking for HTML to do this itself, I'm looking for a tool that combines HTML files on my development machine before I upload them to the production server. The exact opposite of PHP, which is dynamically including the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) is a templating system that can be invoked statically. There are implementations available for Java.

Comment: If you're adding non-html code to the page that changes it dependent on what the code is, how is that not dynamic?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin With PHP `include`, for example, if 100 people visit a web page it is dynamically combined 100 times. Whereas with mustache, it is combined once before shipping it to the web server. After this it is never again combined. If 100 people visit this page, there's still only one combine that has taken place. Thus this page on the web server is static.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have my terminology wrong, the moment you do anything other than straight mark up - for example combining files - it's no longer static html. Barmar's right, the PHP `include` statement is a perfectly fine way to do what you ask.

To literally answer your question, the only way to "merge" static html files is to manually duplicate the code; as soon as you want to start drawing in repeatable assets such as a navigation bar without manually copy and pasting, that's dynamic.

Is there a reason you don't want to either duplicate the code, or use a dynamic language such as PHP?